# java web application - how to create scheduled task or event listener

Tags: java, web-applications, scheduled-tasks, task, event-listener

I'm creating a web application, based on struts.. The thing is, that i need to do some scheduled task, or better than that an event listener...

The idea is that my web app saves some date fields in a database, and i want to make something that checks the content of every rows, and execute a method for the fields which date is the current date.

My problem is that i have never performed a listener or a scheduled task before, and I'm very confused i don't know how to do it.. I've been reading other articles, but i don't get how to integrate it with my webapp..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You may want to consider the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project for scheduling web callbacks for your application. Using _Revalee_ would allow you to schedule future tasks by calling your web app back at a specific date & time. This way all of you code stays right in your web app.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Scheduler is the best one in scheduling a job. Please refer the following links

http://www.javabeat.net/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/

Answer (score 0):

(a) Needing a scheduled task is entirely different than needing an event listener. Focus your question.

(b) For a scheduled task…

The older class bundled with Java is a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

The newer way is a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Each has pros and cons. Search StackOverflow for examples.